# Getting legend in text market plot (python)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I am trying to visualize different manifold learning algorithms on the well-known MNIST dataset. I've replaced each data-point with a text-marker, telling which digit it truly represents. However, I cannot figure out how to add a legend, describing what colors that belongs to what digits.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import offsetbox
from sklearn import (manifold, datasets, decomposition, ensemble)
import seaborn as sns

digits = datasets.load_digits(n_class=10)
X = digits.data
y = digits.target
n_samples, n_features = X.shape

tsne = manifold.TSNE(n_components=2, random_state=0, perplexity=40)
X_t = tsne.fit_transform(X)

X_t=pd.DataFrame(X_t)
y=pd.DataFrame(y)
XY=pd.concat([X_t,y], axis=1)
XY.columns = ['x', 'y', 'digit']

customPalette=sns.hls_palette(10, l=.7, s=1)


fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
axes.set_xlim(XY['x'].min()*0.98,XY['x'].max()*1.02)
axes.set_ylim(XY['y'].min()*0.98,XY['y'].max()*1.02)


for i in range(0,10):
    for l, row in XY.loc[XY['digit']==i,:].iterrows():
        plt.annotate(int(row['digit']), (row['x'], row['y']), 
        horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center', 
        size=10, color=customPalette[i])
        plt.title('t-SNE')
```

Resulting in the following figure:
[image: t-SNE on MNIST]

I would like to add a similar legend as in the following picture:

[Legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uS2RX.png)

Comment: I suggest you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that includes imports and correct indentation. And you attract the right people by adding the tags for the libraries you use.

Comment: Do you need something [like this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/manifold/plot_lle_digits.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-manifold-plot-lle-digits-py)?

Comment: I have updated the description with a picture illustrating what I would like to add to my current plot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
axes.set_xlim(XY['x'].min()*0.98,XY['x'].max()*1.02)
axes.set_ylim(XY['y'].min()*0.98,XY['y'].max()*1.02)

for i in range(0,10):
    k=0
    for l, row in XY.loc[XY['digit']==i,:].iterrows():
        if k==0: 
            plt.plot(row['x'], row['y'], '.', color=customPalette[i], label=int(row['digit']))
            plt.legend(numpoints=1, markerscale=3)
            k += 1    
        plt.annotate(int(row['digit']), (row['x'], row['y']), horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center', size=10, color=customPalette[i])
        plt.title('t-SNE')
```

[image]

Comment: There was a bit problem with the indentation of plt.annotate() and plt.title(). They had to be moved one step further to the right. 
Thanks a lot!